# Python code obfuscation in Docker image/container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, containers

i'm trying to build docker image with python in it in obfuscated form, so i tried below method

```
    FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

COPY hello-world.py /
COPY requirments.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirments.txt
RUN pyarmor obfuscate 'hello-world.py'
RUN rm -rf hello-world.py
RUN cd dist
CMD ["python", "hello-world.py"]
```

i'm getting error at pyarmor command

```
INFO     Start obfuscating the scripts...
INFO        ello-world.py -> dist/ello-world.py
ERROR    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/ello-world.py'
```

need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the original file outside of the root (/) seems to have fixed the issue:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
COPY hello-world.py .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pyarmor obfuscate hello-world.py
RUN rm -rf hello-world.py
CMD ["python", "dist/hello-world.py"]
```

```
docker build -t obf-hello .
... <output omitted> ...

docker run -it --rm obf-hello
HELLO WORLD!
```

Comment: A lots of Thanx, its working

Answer (score 2):

When building a Docker image, it is always important to remember that any statement (`FROM`, `COPY`, `RUN` etc.) creates a new layer, and that all layers remain accessible by anyone who will later access the image:

```
$ docker history obf-hello
IMAGE          CREATED              CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
faf859dcd93b   45 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python" "dist/hello…   0B        
db189a78c052   46 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c rm -rf hello-world.py                0B        
bb39d058fd4f   47 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c pyarmor obfuscate hello-world.py     1.22MB    
c2b29debdf25   49 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt      10.1MB    
dbf9cde1f691   52 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5bf416045dde3b2a…   15B       
8e632b7679ea   53 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:8c0ca98b3d5632b9…   46B       
2020b38099a5   54 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app                  0B        
b8eba45cc77a   55 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get insta…   432MB     
13d7ab1c648b   About a minute ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nonin…   0B        
dcf4d4bef137   2 weeks ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:c6039a4f004b6b6c2…   63.2MB    
$ docker run --rm bb39d058fd4f cat hello-world.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("HELLO WORLD!")
```

To avoid the disclosure of your sources (no matter you use Python, Java, Go or anything else), use multi-stage builds as described in Docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

For the original question, I would suggest something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic as build

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM build as temp
COPY hello-world.py .
RUN pyarmor obfuscate hello-world.py

FROM build as dist
COPY --from=temp /app/dist/ dist/
CMD ["python", "dist/hello-world.py"]
```

And please notice I've removed `RUN rm -rf hello-world.py` because it is just an extra step having no sense.